# How to mitre a long edge with home tools

Tags: wood

I am trying to work out how to mitre a long edge of wood for example the edge of a panel around 1m. I need to cut various non standard angles on different edges to make a cabinet not just 45 degree cuts. How could I achieve this at home?  I know you can do that sort of thing with an industrial circular table saw but that is out of my budget. Is there a way I can do this with home tooling?

Update:  Sorry I guess I mean bevel the edge for a panel of wood at different angles.  I've got a mitre saw but it can only do lengths of up to about 20cm.  By home tooling I mean what the average guy has in his garage and not using specialist industrial factory grade equipment.

Comment: Seems like a better question for http://woodworking.stackexchange.com. At a minimum I suggesting editing to explain what tools you have available. What does "home tooling" mean? As it is, the question is vastly broad in scope.

Comment: Circular saws can typically do bevel cuts to about 45°.

Comment: @isherwood right. Also do you mean mitre or bevel?